# Opening Photoshop CC in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, photoshop, creative-cloud

I am trying to use a VB.NET program we have which worked perfectly fine with Photoshop before it moved to CC. Now it hasn't been working and I'm not sure why. The problem it is having is with actually opening Photoshop. It throws an error for the line

```
PhotoshopApp = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Photoshop.Application"))
```

where PhotoshopApp is just a Photoshop.Application. The error I'm getting is

> "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {*names the CLSID*} failed due to the following error: 80080005."

Any help would be amazing. I don't know what changed in the Creative Cloud versions but it makes it much more difficult to work with.

Comment: Do you have earlier versions of Photoshop installed? [COMException and Photoshop classes missing in Object Model Viewer after installing Photoshop CC 2015](https://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family/topics/comexception-and-photoshop-classes-missing-in-object-model-viewer-after-installing-photoshop-cc-2015) seems to say that that can cause the registry entries to be in a muddle.

Comment: Also, have a look at [Possible to interact with a 64-bit COM server (Photoshop) from .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5974568/1115360)

Comment: Hi @AndrewMorton Thank you so much for the response. I do not have earlier versions of Photoshop installed. And i don't think the 64-bit COM is the problem. Because the program I have used to run on Photoshop CS5 and it would work great. Trying to upgrade to Photoshop CC has made it stop working. I've tried giving new Photoshop.dll and new Interop.Photoshop.dll , but nothing seems to work. Any other ideas? Again I really appreciate your response, thank you

Comment: I think that PS CS5 was a 32-bit program. PS CS6 was definitely available as both 32- and 64-bit, and I think you were given a choice in the installer. PS CC may be available as a 32-bit program, but it might take some digging to find it, or it could be that both 32-bit and 64-bit versions get installed. If you start PS manually, then you can check in Task Manager in the "Processes" tab if it is a 32-bit program (it will say if it is).

Comment: @AndrewMorton I checked task manager and I dont see anything that says 32 or 64 bit, and Googling says CS6 and on will install 32 or 64 bit depending on the machine. So since I have a 64 bit machine I would assume its 64 bit. But either way in Visual Studio I'm adding this Photoshop 2020 as a reference which creates a new Interop.Photoshop.dll , so I would think that should let it work. I wish this error I was getting was more specific because I've tried so many things and can't get this to work

Comment: Is the project set to run as 32-bit, 64-bit, or Any CPU? Perhaps try a different setting.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I just went thru and tried each setting and unfortunately none of them worked. It still gets stuck at the same place with the same error. I really appreciate you giving me the ideas you have because I've tried everything I can think of. Its frustrating

Comment: Maybe the ProgID needs to be different - if you search the registry for the CLSID, perhaps it will lead you to something, although check with the first link I gave in case there are some other relevant ones. If you could make a Hyper-V machine with a fresh copy of Windows and install the tryout copy of PS CC on it, then you could see if it works on that - perhaps that would be a better option than looking at all those hard-to-read GUIDs in the registry.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't put my program on a Hyper-V machine because this is program for work and they don't really let us transfer our programs anywhere unless we get permission to move it into Production. I did go into the registry for the CLSID I keep getting and I tried giving full control permissions everything using the registry. And STILL my program doesn't work.

Comment: Can you get (perhaps via your manager) the people who won't let you do it to try it for you? Tell them it is holding up production, if that is true.

Comment: my application photohsop album making software is working Photoshop CS3 to Photoshop CC2020 x32 and x64 without any issues .....every launching i check currently running photoshop is x32 or x64..see the sample codes here .. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MVkHs1roWMA